# Fatjar with maven-assembly-plugin - No auto configuration classes found in META-INF/spring.factories

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, maven-3, maven-assembly-plugin

I built a simple **Spring Boot** application with `maven-assembly-plugin`.

Below is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
            <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>
            jar-with-dependencies
            </descriptorRef>
            </descriptorRefs>
            <archive>
            <manifest>
            <mainClass>com.example.demo.DemoApplication</mainClass>
            </manifest>
            </archive>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
            <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
            <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            </execution>
            </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I generate jar using `maven clean install`.

Once I run the fatjar as `java -jar fatjar.jar`, I see below error:

> No auto configuration classes found in META-INF/spring.factories. If
> you are using a custom packaging, make sure that file is correct

I even tried adding META-INF folder with `spring.factories` in it. Did not work.

Comment: If you use spring boot please use the spring-boot-maven-plugin because a spring boot application has a special bootstrap mechanism which is hard to create via maven-assembly-plugin...

Comment: i have some jars added in my lib folder which are pointed to it via systempath in my pom.xml. When i use  spring-boot-maven-plugin, those files are not visible.

Comment: Use the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` and tell it to include system scoped dependencies (see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/5510#issuecomment-360475856).